# Bootstrap Dropdown not working Locally but works on Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an `MVC 5` webapp and trying to create a split drop down button.  My code works on Fiddle just fine:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
     <button id="ClearRules" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Clear all of the rules"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Clear</button>
     <button id="AddRule" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Add a new rule"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</button>
     <button id="AddRules" class="btn btn-xs btn-default dropdown-toggle" title="Add several rules" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span class="caret"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

My `js` and `css` bundles include `bootstrap`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-dialog.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-dialog.css"));
```

I even copied the example from the `Boostrap` site and dropped it into my code to no avail.  The button appears correctly but the drop down does not expand when it is clicked.

Edit:

Here are my script and style imports exactly as they appear in the rendered html head.  As suggested by Andrei, I was wondering if I might be missing something or importing something in the wrong order:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Tether/Tether.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>    
<script src="/Scripts/TheRandomizer.ItemListMaintenance.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of very common mistakes causing this issue is loading jquery file twice.
I suggest you using *View page Source* and *inspect* in the browser menu go to source code and search for jquery and make sure you cannot find jquery twice in the output html

Comment: This was the  issue, I don't know when or how it happened but there were Script.Render calls at the end of my _layout.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

a) check console for any errors.

b) check for any of these common issues:

- you're not loading `jquery(.min).js`
- you're not loading `bootstrap(.min).js`
- you're not loading `jquery(.min).js` before `bootstrap(.min).js`
- you're not loading `tether(.min).js` before `bootstrap(.min).js` and you're using v4.

Unfortunately, without you being able to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your error (which you say you can't), that's about all the help I can provide. Best of luck!