# Bootstrap modal not working in React typescript app but working on the fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

As per my current research:

- [assets are already added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57248729/2404470)
- [tried removing fade class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612480/2404470), no difference
- [jQuery is not loading twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592447/2404470)
- [assets are loaded in the order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42590484/2404470), no difference as such

Here is a debug version https://preprod-ansaar.web.app/

I have implemented a bootstrap modal in my `app.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
const app: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button id="btn1">Show Modal</button>
      <br />
      <button data-onclick="alert('Button Clicked')">Another Button</button>


      <div className="modal fade" id="myModal" data-tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <button className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 className="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              Modal Body
      </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default app;
```

My `index.css` is:

```
#myModal {
  position: relative;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

And in the `index.html` I have:

```
  <script>
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
      // reset modal if it isn't visible
      if (!($('.modal.in').length)) {
        $('.modal-dialog').css({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        });
      }
      $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: false,
        show: true
      });

      $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header"
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The same code is generating a draggable modal while keeping background usable [on the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntLpg6hw/11/)

The same is not working in my React app, can anyone please guide on this?

Comment: The click handlers are registered before the dom is ready which makes it redundant. Try moving the  click handlers to  componentDidMount.

cdm("$('#btn1').click(handler fn))).

And the fiddle works because dom is already initialized (Since you are not using react there) before the script executes.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: @nithin yes correct! This solved my problem!

Comment: Happy coding 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@nithin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1716634/nithin) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343905/bootstrap-modal-not-working-in-react-typescript-app-but-working-on-the-fiddle?noredirect=1#comment101179156_57343905)
The click handlers are registered before the `DOM` is ready which makes it redundant. Try moving the click handlers to `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {    
    //modal logic goes here    
}
```

And the fiddle works because `DOM` is already initialized (Since you are not using react there) before the script executes

Answer (score 0):

Use React strap .

> npm i reactstrap

```
<Modal isOpen={true}><Modal/>
```

Comment: I wish to keep the background useable too, this doesn't satisfy what I need